# Proving this semidirect product is an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

I've been trying to solve the following question, but am unable to fully complete the required proof.

> Let $p$ be a prime number, $C$ a cyclic group of order $p$ and $N$ a finite
> group such that $Aut(N)$ has a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup of order $p$. Prove that
> for every non-trivial $\phi_1, \phi_2 : C \to Aut(N)$, we have: $N \rtimes_{\phi_1} C \cong N \rtimes_{\phi_2} C$.

We may assume $C$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ since: $N \rtimes_{\phi_1} C \cong N \rtimes_{\phi_1} \mathbb{Z}_p \cong N \rtimes_{\phi_2} \mathbb{Z}_p \cong N \rtimes_{\phi_2} C $.

Since a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup is unique, we know that the only options for homomorphisms $\phi_i$ are defined by:

$$ \phi_i : \mathbb{Z}_p \to Aut(N)$$
$$ 1 \mapsto \alpha^i$$

where $\alpha$ is an automorphism of order $p$ from the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup. There are no other homomorphisms, since, if there are, they must be of order $p$ (being non-trivial) and therefore there is another $p$-Sylow subgroup of order $p$ -- contradiction.

**Now I want to prove that for every such $\phi_1, \phi_2$ we have:
$$ N \rtimes_{\phi_1} \mathbb{Z}_p \cong N \rtimes_{\phi_2} \mathbb{Z}_p $$
but because of the presence of the semi-direct product, I'm not sure how to construct such an isomorphism. How does one approach such a construction?**

Comment: You say you want to solve the following question, but I cannot see a question. I can just see a statement. What are you asking? Are you asking whether the statement is true?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks - clarified.

Comment: Hint: If there is only one non-trivial homomorphism into $Aut(N)$, what can you say about the two homomorphism $\phi_1,\phi_2$.

Comment: @NoahSolomon What do you mean? If there is only one that's non-trivial then there is nothing to prove (the claim vacuously holds, no?)

Comment: @Anon yes, and while this is not quite the case in this problem, you do get an isomorphism between their images, try to work with that.

Comment: @NoahSolomon Thanks, but I'm really not following your line of thought. How does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality we may assume that $\phi_1(1) = \alpha$ and so there exists some $n \in \{1,\dots,p-1\}$ such that $\phi_2(1) =\alpha^n$. Since $C_p$ is cyclic, these values entirely determine $\phi_1,\phi_2$. One way to think of this is the the $n$-th power map is an isomorphism between the image of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$. Then we want to use this map to construct an isomorphism between the semidirect products. Let $m$ be the inverse of $n$ modulo $p$, i.e. $mn \equiv 1 \mod p$. Consider the map $\psi:N \rtimes_{\phi_1} C_p\to N \rtimes_{\phi_2} C_p$ defined by $$\psi(g,i) = (g,mi).$$ Hopefully it is clear that this is a bijection so it just remains to show that it is a homomorphism. For this we can see that$$\psi((g,i)(h,j)) = \psi(g\alpha^i(h),i+j) = (g\alpha^i(h),m(i+j)).$$
On the other hand,
$$ \psi(g,i)\psi(h,j) = (g,mi)(h,mj) = (g{(\alpha^{n})}^{mi}(h),mi+mj) = (g\alpha^{mni}(h),m(i+j)) = (g\alpha^i(h),m(i+j)).$$ Note that in this second computation we are working with the product in $N \rtimes_{\phi_2} C_p$, hence we have a factor of $n$ appearing in the power of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks. What led you to the definition $\psi(g,i) = (g,mi)$? I feel that I can verify your solution, but that  if I had a similar question I wouldn't know how to think about which definition would end up leading to an isomorphism. Would I just guess and 'correct'?

Comment: @Anon good question, I was trying to hint at this in my comment, but evidently not very well. The idea is to account for difference between $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ in how we define $\psi$. So if $\phi_2$ gives us an additional factor of $n$ in the exponent of $\alpha$, we want to undo this, by multiplying by the inverse of $n$ (mod $p$). In practice, one could also just guess that we want to multiply the second coordinate by something and then tweak it until we get something works.

Comment: Just started to get the idea and your last comment really drove it home. Thanks!!! Really do appreciate it -- you helped me clarify this issue that has been bothering me on several of these.